# How to prevent thumbnail stretching in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to prevent my thumbnails from stretching on my website when search results are shown.

My website is [www.thehungryeurasian.com](http://www.thehungryeurasian.com)

To search for a label, select 'I'm hungry for' in navigation bar, then click any of the options below.

This is the javascript that I used:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var thumbnail_mode = "no-float" ;
  summary_noimg = 300;
  summary_img = 350; 
  img_thumb_height = 200; 
  img_thumb_width = 300;
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[
    function removeHtmlTag(strx,chop) {
      if(strx.indexOf("<")!=-1) {
        var s = strx.split("<");
        for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++) {
          if(s[i].indexOf(">")!=-1) {
            s[i] = s[i].substring(s[i].indexOf(">")+1,s[i].length);
          }
        }
        strx = s.join("");
      }
    chop = (chop < strx.length-1) ? chop : strx.length-2;
    while(strx.charAt(chop-1)!=' ' && strx.indexOf(' ',chop)!=-1) chop++;
    strx = strx.substring(0,chop-1);
    return strx+'...';
  }

  function createSummaryAndThumb(pID){
    var div = document.getElementById(pID);
    var imgtag = "";
    var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var summ = summary_noimg;
    if(img.length>=1) {
      imgtag = '<span style="float:left; padding:0px 10px 5px 0px;"><img src="'+img[0].src+'" width="'+img_thumb_width+'px" height="'+img_thumb_height +'px"/></span>';
      summ = summary_img;
    }
    var summary = imgtag + '<div>' + removeHtmlTag(div.innerHTML,summ) + '</div>';
    div.innerHTML = summary;
  }
//]]>
</script>
```

However, every time I've tried to edit the size of the image in CSS, it would edit all the images on my website, rather than just those that appear in the search results.

Comment: Please use the `max-width` attribute for your `img` element or try using `width="auto"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set only the following code in your CSS file. Use selectors to target more specific images.

```
/* CSS */
img { height: auto; }
```

or

```
/* CSS */
.post-body img { height: auto; }
```

Comment: Thank you, thats amazing! I think I tried to make min too complex.